# @font-face en css no me funciona

Tags: css

He intentado este codigo pero no me funciona en ningun navegador quisiera saber en que estoy fallando.

```
  /*fonts*/
    @font-face{
        font-family: 'Lato-Regular';
        src: url('../Fonts/Lato-Regular.eot');
        src: url('../Fonts/Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
        url('../Fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype')
        url('../Fonts/Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff')   
        url('../Fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2') format('woff2')
        url('../Fonts/Lato-Regular.svg#Lato-Regular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    
    h1{
        font-family: 'Lato-Regular';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te estás sobre complicando, sería más simple esto:

```css
.latoClass {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="latoClass">
  hola ola
</h1>
<h1>
  hola hola
</h1>
</body>
```

Aunque con el `ttf` como lo tienes tu, puedes hacerlo de este modo, pero siento que demora más que el otro.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  src: url('698242188-Lato-Bla.eot');
  src: url('698242188-Lato-Bla.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('698242188-Lato-Bla.svg#Lato Black') format('svg'),
    url('698242188-Lato-Bla.woff') format('woff'),
    url('698242188-Lato-Bla.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.latoClass {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="latoClass">
  hola ola
</h1>
<h1>
  hola hola
</h1>
```